# Can I get a general solution of this recurrence relation?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I want to solve this recurrence relation; 
$${ a }_{ n }=3{ a }_{ n-1 }-{ a }_{ n-3 } \quad(n\ge 3) $$$$({ a }_{ 0 }=1,\quad { a }_{ 1 }=3,\quad { a }_{ 2 }=9)$$

First, I use characteristic equation; 
$${ x }^{ 3 }-3{ x }^{ 2 }+1=0$$
But, the roots are so complex....

Second, I use generating function $\quad G(x)=\sum _{ n=0 }^{  }{ { a }_{ n }{ x }^{ n } } \quad$ , then I have just this equation; $$G(x)=(1+3x-{ x }^{ 3 })G(x),\quad so\quad G(x)=\frac { 1 }{ 1-3x+{ x }^{ 3 } } $$

Now, I wonder if it is actually possible to get a general solution.

Comment: That characteristic equation has 3 real roots.....

Comment: https://oeis.org/A076264

Comment: Using generating functions is **more complicated**  that directly using the fact that $u_n=Ar_1^n+Br_2^n+Cr_3^n$ where the $r_k$ are the roots of the characteristic equation... for certain coefficients $A,B,C$ given by the initial conditions.

Comment: If you use the trigonometric method for solving ${ x }^{ 3 }-3{ x }^{ 2 }+1=0$, the roots are not so complex since $$r_1=1+2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)$$ $$r_2=1-\sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)$$ $$r_3=1-\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{9}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)$$

Comment: thanks for all reply. now i can get a general solution using a generating function:)